# When I press ⌘ + N I get an error that says "no source actions available" when in a text file

Tags: visual-studio-code

I don't know what happened to my vscode but when I press `⌘ + N` I get an error that says `no source actions available`.

This used to work fine. I'm in a text file when doing this. If I go to the menu and look at what the shortcut for `new text file` is, it shows `⌘ + N`.

Is something misconfigured?

Comment: Probably. Did you look at your key mappings?

Comment: You are right, seems like an extension has added that keybinding for inside the document.